# Trac losing sync with repo on every git reset

Tags: git, trac

I've setup Trac 1.0 and synced with my git repo. 
While playing with the [CommitTicketUpdater](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) and trying to close issues with git commit using provided syntax as: "closes #1" or "close #1" or "fixes #1" [which-did-not-work], I had to reset couple of times the branch to reverse my command commit. Every time I dd the reset, trac lost sync and to I had to resync doing:

> trac-admin /path/to/project repository resync "*"

That shit is nasty, and takes some time to complete.
Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to reset branch and not loose sync?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Trac and git operate on different paradigms.  Git is perfectly happy allowing you to alter history by un-doing commits, re-ordering revisions, etc.  Trac assumes a linear, immutable timeline (remember that it was designed for use with Subversion).  When you commit with a message that closes the ticket, the ticket is closed inside Trac's database.  When you reset a commit, Trac doesn't go back and update its own timeline to match the new git timeline.  Re-syncing is a laborious process (as you've discovered), but it's the only way for you to tell Trac that the timeline has been altered.

One way around this problem is to have Trac monitor a different repository than the one you use for your development work.  Only push changes to Trac's repo once you've tested them and can be fairly certain that you won't have to revert.  That will keep the timeline linear from Trac's point of view, but will still allow you to use all of git's features normally.

This is actually a hard problem to solve for any system.  When you change the git repository's timeline in a way that affects commits with ticket open/close commands (for instance), you risk changing the ticket number of a ticket or the order of ticket comments.  This breaks any existing links or references to those items.

One way to make sure that your repository changes are kept in sync with your issue tracker is to use a system like [bugs everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/) that stores the bug list/details inside the repository.  Tools like this typically aren't as full-featured as Trac, but their distributed nature may better fit with a distributed version control system.

Comment: I do realize that git and trac are different systems, I just looked for a project management solution that integrates with git. Having different repo just for trac sync is not effective, but it's a possibility. I think that I've misjudged the integration capabilities between git and trac, and I might get to look for other project management solution for my repo.

Comment: Trac developers a pretty much aware of the current repository handling limitations. Bit it'll take some time to work it out. Would still be interesting to see, if other management tools do better in this respect. IMHO Trac is a reference regarding usability, that still holds.

Answer (score 0):

To use the CommitTicketUpdater, I created a bare repository and added the following hooks to it: https://gist.github.com/kenaniah/5471280 (drop those in the repo's hooks directory without the .sh extension and make them executable).

I then added a cron job to call `git fetch; hooks/post-fetch` and now trac is automatically notified of only new commits, regardless of the branching structure.

Comment: That could be a good workaround, but I've lost faith in that bond, and started using Github Issues. But again, for those who still want to use Trac, that could be the solution.